# Run Local site using UniServer Zero

Tags: magento-2.1, localhost

Does anyone have tried to setup **`Magento 2.1`** at **`UniServer Zero`** as Local server?

Comment: Have you checked the current version of PHP? Does it satisfy which version your Magento setup requires?

Comment: Hi @MohitKumarArora, Yes, it does comply the version and requirements of Magento. The UniServer Zero was using PHP 7.1.1. After completed the setup, there's no body content and admin page was blank.

Comment: Have you checked Magento log and apache server's logs?

Comment: Under the system.log, I got these

System.log

[2019-01-15 06:25:39] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/Users/s993015/Downloads/zkill/UniServerZ/www/mage/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js' [] []
[2019-01-15 06:25:39] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:/Users/s993015/Downloads/zkill/UniServerZ/www/mage/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []...

Comment: Maybe you have missing dependencies. You need to run **`composer update`** to fix this.